# Bootstrap row still creates gap on right even there are columns inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I have  a page where container-fluid is the main div and then nav comes. After nav I have section where views loading in with row wrapping up content which is divided in columns or offsetted. But When I use a row class either on section or the div after , it is creating a gap between nav and page. Mainly adding it to container. But that is why we should be using container. And row is for columns so why still the gap?

```
<div class="container-fluid ng-scope" id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="homeCtrl as ctrl">
<nav><div class="container"></div></nav>
<section>
<div ng-controller="assumeIdCtrl as ctrl" class="row ng-scope">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code is not sufficient, please create a clear demo and desired outcome. you can fork https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/1axxbg22/

Comment: I actually found the problem by the help of Joël Bonet Rodríguez. I did not need a div before nav. Nav works like a row in itself and when Section has container-fluid,  row class works fine after that. So the above code is now redundant. But you can see problem here with the row and nav difference https://jsfiddle.net/tekin/e6d68toz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use default bootstrap's nav, you can copy the code from W3C.
Then make your structure correctly like, for example:

```
<nav> </nav>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Check that there are different container types. div, nav, aside, section, footer, etc are containers by default. It's ok and awesome to use bootstrap, but we have to remember the default atributes of HTML tags before aply bootstrap.

Try with the default bootstrap's fixed nav. 
I made an example of portfolio using it, you can check and inspect here:

[portfolio example](http://ilercode.com/peppermint/pracboot/)

it's very clean concerning js (only one jQ function if i dont remember wrong) and there's only a bit of handmaded css.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav Here Bootstrap gives container-fluid as part of nav where nav links are wrapped. And I have a generic container. Should I get rid of generic container then? But rows are also need to be in container it says.

Comment: Yes I looked at site, interesting you don't use row there but columns. I think row -15px margins is the issue but I don't want to overwrite generic bootstrap values. Sure those other HTML container can be use and I thought section in my case could be a row and nav is another row.

Comment: Actually I think I was doing it wrong by making the firs container necessary and fluid here I found an example works best for me because I need full width for dashboard. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: Most issues are coming when you take piece of bootstrap's code that you found on forums. In the portfolio that i pasted, i use a jQuery function to read the height, some people try to do it with css for example. 

you have to visualize first what you want to do, then start writting open tag and close tag of each div, nav, etc with the class desired to do what you want.
You can use more of 1 container on a page, if you need a dashboard, check this one i made: 
http://peppermint.ilercode.com/
user: guest@guest.com
pass: guest1234

cheers!